# Best way to classify Messy Text Data of Product Description

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

A pipeline of Word Embeddings + Feature Extraction + Classifier is often used in Text Classification (categories such as Dress, Toys, Food, etc.) but **this assumes a lot of things in the data being well-structured**. 
What about techniques for classifying text data that are full of typographical errors (e.g. *"RUBBER DUCK TYS"*) , missing spaces (e.g. *"PINKPOLYESTERDRESSES"*), bunch of inserted random words (e.g. *"INTEL CHIP 220mg 1104 OLD TOWN ST.*), etc.?

I know n-gram approach + a classifier can be used here but

1. using n-gram is probably computationally expensive (imagine having a
   dataset composed of 100 million product entries that are like that
2. impossible to use embeddings in n-grams (DRESS VS SHIRT using
   trigrams)

What do you think are some approaches applicable to this?

Answer (score 0):

*n*-gram based methods require the input text to be even better structured. Typically, you represent the input as a bag of *n*-grams, so rely on exact the same *n*-grams appearing in the training data and the test data. On the other hand, when using pre-trained embeddings, similar words are represented similarly, so you do not need to see the exact same words in the training and test data.

There are also methods for learning *n*-gram embeddings (e.g., https://github.com/artetxem/phrase2vec) but they only pay off if you have a really large data like millions of sentences.

In this case, I would say, you should focus on cleaning your data. (Removing stop-words, OOVs and some normalization should help.)

Comment: when you said using pre-trained embeddings, do you mean GloVe? Does BERT use pre-trained embedding? my problem would be normalizing them. so what do you suggest on that? probably some sort of XLNET + something

Comment: I meant non-contextualized embeddings, GloVe or FastText. Contextual embeddings (BERT, XLNet, ...) are also worth trying, depends on how noisy your input is. They are pre-trained but do not use pre-trained embeddings, they train their own token embeddings. By normalization, I meant hand-crafted rules, filtering out weird stuff from text.